# Need Help w/ SharePoint CAML Query

Tags: sharepoint, list, caml

Here's what I'm doing (this is a quick search on Google and just one of the first results):

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc300163(v=office.12).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc300163%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

My databound DropDownList items looks like this:

```
<listitem>All Providers</listitem>
<listitem>Provider 1</listitem>
<listitem>Provider 2</listitem>
```

My current CAML query in the view looks like:

```
<Query>
 <Where>
  <And>
   <Or>
    <Eq>
     <FieldRef Name="Status" />
     <Value Type="Lookup">Submitted</Value>
    </Eq>
    <Eq>
     <FieldRef Name="Status" />
     <Value Type="Lookup">In Progress</Value>
    </Eq>
   </Or>
   <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name="Provider"/>
    <Value Type="Text">{Param1}</Value>
   </Eq>
  </And>
 </Where>
 <OrderBy>
  <FieldRef Name="ID" Ascending="FALSE"></FieldRef>
 </OrderBy>
</Query>
```

What I NEED is this...

In psuedocode:

*If {Param1} equals "All Providers" just filter on Status where Status is equal to "Submitted" or "In Progress"
 else if {Param1} is not equal to "All Providers" filter on Status and Provider where Status is equal to "Submitted" or "In Progress" and Provider is equal to {Param1}*

How do I put this into View XML schema?

I know it can be done as Microsoft already uses it in SharePoint and there's 3rd-party controls that do it.

For example...

1) In SP, click on "Lists" in the left nav menu.

2) To the far right, under the search box', you'll see "View:" with a dropdown.

3) Based on which view you choose, the URL's querystring contains "BaseType" that changes to the value of your choice.  If "All Site Content" is chosen, the "BaseType" is left out of the querystring.

Thanks,
Joshua

Comment: You don't mention what version of SharePoint, but with 2007, you can use the U2U CAML Query Builder (http://www.u2u.net/res/Tools/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx) to build your queries.  This has saved me lots of headaches.

Comment: CAML Query Builder works fine with SharePoint 2010 as well. Link: http://www.u2u.net/res/Tools/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx

Answer (score 1):

First off, I think you are better off [adding a filter webpart](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/connect-a-filter-web-part-to-a-data-view-web-part-HA010250997.aspx) for the Provider field, as this allows you to not filter with a blank value.

If you *must* have a parameter that filters on "All Providers" you can create a calculated field on the list call AllProviders say, with the formula:

```
="All Providers"
```

This then allows your query clause to be entered thusly:

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <And>
      <Or>
        <Eq>
          <FieldRef Name="AllProviders"/>
          <Value Type="Text">{Param1}</Value>
        </Eq>
        <Eq>
          <FieldRef Name="Provider"/>
          <Value Type="Text">{Param1}</Value>
        </Eq>
      </Or>
      <Or>
        <Eq>
          <FieldRef Name="Status"/>
          <Value Type="Lookup">In Progress</Value>
        </Eq>
        <Eq>
          <FieldRef Name="Status"/>
          <Value Type="Lookup">Submitted</Value>
        </Eq>
      </Or>
    </And>
  </Where>
</Query>
```

The Status field will always match either "In Progress" or "Submitted".

If your parameter = "All Providers" then you will match the calculated field, otherwise you will match on the Provider field.

Note that this does prevent you from having a Provider call "All Providers".